# Out Of Scope Summary Unavailable while debugging

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios5, scope

I am developing a simple iPhone game. I am using a `if else if else if else` loop. When I am trying to debug the else part and I keep cursor above variables,it is showing a `'out of scope Summary Unavailable'` message.

I am sure that braces are proper and the same works fine for other else if's and if part of the loop.

Why is it happening?

Please help.

Comment: out of scope is happening for 'for' loops, i.e;i can't get count of 'i'.Even boolean values are showing this,also the int values...

Comment: have you declared some variable in side some {  } and trying to access it from outside?

Comment: Post some code to exactly get to the root of the problem.

Comment: actually i have solves it,so I'm not posting code,i am new to this will try to post using proper syntax and grammar next time,sorry...thanks Parth Bhatt for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your variable which you are using, might be you are accessing them out of their scope, try to use unique variable names.

Comment: yes thanx man ,it was a silly mistake i made,when i changed all the variable names,it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Put break point just below your variable and type following in console gdb

- p "your variable name if its primitive type like int"
- po "your object name"

This will print the value in them.